# Windows Workflow Foundation 4 run only one workflow

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

I need that would be one time moment run only one workflow. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Use WorkflowInvoker or WorkflowApplication and you have full control over which workflow runs when.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to test your workflow, use WorkflowInvoker.
If you want to be able to receive message (i.e. waiting for an input) and be about to test the persistence, monitoring of the workflow instance, use WorkflowApplication.